# PNG image from java server to android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send multiple PNG:s to an adroid-phone.
(Every image is sent in a separate JSON-object together with multiple other objects that is associated with the image.) 
I'm sending the images as byte-arrays and my phone is receiving them.
The problem starts when I try to decode with `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` which returns `null`.
How should I encode on the server-side and decode on the android-side?

First attempt on server-side:

```
File imgPath = new File(path);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);
WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
byte[] bytes = data.getData();
```

Second attempt on server-side:

```
byte[] bytes = null;    
File file = new File(path);
bytes =  Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

Android-side:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Sending JSON from server:

```
public class Response {
    List<Person> mPeople;
    ..other objects...
}

public class Person {
    String name;
    String image; //base68string
}

public ServerThread {
    Response resp = create objects to send;      
    String str = new Gson().toJson(resp);
    OutputStreamWriter.write(str);
}
```

Receiving JSON on Android-side:

```
Response resp = gson.fromJson(str, Response.class);
List<Person> = resp.getPersons();
//Person-class on the android side is Parcable
```

So I tried this approach but it still doesn't work:

```
 // Server-side
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
File file = new File(path);
byte[] bytes =  Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
Encoder e = Base64.getEncoder();    
String base64String = e.encodeToString(bytes);

//Android-side
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Fetching `InputStream` from server and using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream)` would be better option.

Comment: There is not much json visible on server side. I wonder why you mess around with a BufferedImage class if the only thing you want to do is placing that png file in a byte array before base64 encoding that array and put the resulting string in the json text. The second attempt is the way to go. But add base64 encoding yet.

Comment: JSON doesn't support binary data or raw byte arrays, how do you represent the image in JSON? Please, show a JSON and code how you deal with it on both sides.

Comment: I've added the code for JSON/GSON. The byte-array is received though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load image into imageview directly from the URL. You don't have to manage this all stuff manually.

I was doing that stuff but after using one of this library it removes lots of work.

Just try this.